# Typescript: Object property returns "undefined"

Tags: typescript, object, undefined

I was working on a function and I want it to check the username for signin API call. My code are as below:

```
export const signIn = async (AuthUser: IAuthUser) => {
  try {

    const userData = await execute<IAuthUser>(AuthQueries.SignIn, [AuthUser.email]);

    console.log(userData.email);  // undefined
    console.log(userData); // log object data {user1email.com, password_for_user1}

    return userData;

  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

So the question is why userData.email returns undefined, while userData has values?
And how to fix that?

Comment: Show the ***actual*** value of `userData`. `{user1email.com, password_for_user1}` isn't useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I realised that `userData` is getting result from MySQL query using the `"mysql2": "^2.3.3"` package and the result is a `RowDataPacket` object.
This way, I can access the `userData` values by index.

For example:

```
console.log(userData[0].email); //returns the actual value
```